# Updating HTML Based on select/option value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a little problem at the moment :( I've got a short form asking for a value of money, and below that, there's a bit of jQuery validation which calculates 20 percent of the selected price, and subtracts it from the selected price, then updates it to the empty span tag.

The problem is, the code isn't wrong (all the other functions in the same block work), but this does nothing, at all!

```
<select id="list"><option value="error">$-</option><option value="1">$1</option><option value="5">$5</option><option value="10">$10</option><option value="25">$25</option><option value="50">$50</option><option value="100">$100</option><option value="250">$250</option><option value="500">$500</option></select>
$<span id="jsprice"></span>
 <script>
   var price = $("#list :selected").val();
    var earning = price-((price/100)*20);
    $('#list').change(function(){
    $('#jsprice').val(earning);
    });
    </script>
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong with this? I tried `.blur() .change()` and a few others, and tried

```
$('#jsprice').val() = earning;
```

but I figured that was just plain wrong, seeing as to how .text() works.

Thanks very much! Any responses greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#list').change(function(){
  var price = $(this).val();
  var earning = price-((price/100)*20);
  $('#jsprice').text(earning);
});
```

this should do it.

Here is a fiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/JeW57/

Comment: This is correct, but just to clarify, instead of `$("#list :selected").val();`, you could use `this.value`.

Comment: heh, I ment `this` as the raw js object, `$(this).value` will return undefined

Answer (score 5):

Spans don't have values - use `.text()` or `.html()` to set the content between the starting and closing tags.

You'll also want to get the value of the select and calculate the value of earning **inside** the `change` callback function, otherwise it will only ever reflect the initial value of the select.