# get row to paragraph from array that includes the selected countrie from options

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

'I don't know how i can do this:'
'If Belgium is selected:'
'show in paragraph: Belgium has a population of 11.46 million people and is 30689 large.'
'I tried different options but all failed, i hope someone can help me out!'

```
    const countries = [
            {name: 'Belgium', population: 11.46, km: 30689},
            {name: 'France', population: 67.06, km: 643801},
            {name: 'USA', population: 238.2, km: 9834000},
            {name: 'Russia', population: 144.4, km: 17130000},
            {name: 'China', population: 1398, km: 9597000},
        ];       
'Create and append the options'
        let countriesList  = document.getElementById('countries').options;    
        countries.forEach(countrie =>
            countriesList.add(
            new Option(countrie.name, countrie.population, countrie.km)
                )
         );
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById("countries").value;
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546535/updating-html-based-on-select-option-value) - perhaps a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Each country has 3 subjects, but an `<option>` has only a `value` attribute and at the area between the tags for text. In order to cram all of that info into one `<option>` I used `JSON.stringified()` on the country object and assigned it as the value and then `country.name` as the text the user can see. It's important to remember that any value whether it be `value`, `class`, `data-*`, is a string. `country` in it's original form is an object literal so the easiest way to store it was to stringify it.

```
opt.value = JSON.stringify(country);
opt.textContent = country.name;
```

As for the function that displays the data as it is selected by the user is handled by binding the `<select>` to the "change" event. So when the user clicks on the `<select>` and picks an `<option>`, as soon as the user releases the mouse button the "change" event is triggered and the event handler is invoked.

```
// <select> is bound to the change event
list.onchange = countryStats;
// This is the event handler
function countryStats(e) {...
```

Inside the event handler the value of the selected `<option>` is extracted and then `JSON.parse()` returns the `country` string back to an object. The data is then interpolated into a template literal of some HTML. The htmlString will be rendered to DOM.

```
list.onchange = countryStats;

function countryStats(e) {
  const data = JSON.parse(this.value); // String to object
  const htmlString = ` 
    <dl>
      <dt>Country</dt>
      <dd>${data.name}</dd>
      <dt>Population</dt> // Template literal in the form of an htmlString
      <dd>${data.population} million</dd>
      <dt>Area</dt>
      <dd>${data.km} km</dd>
    </dl>`;
      const display = document.querySelector('output');
      display.replaceChildren(); // Area cleared
      display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString); 
      /* HTML is rendered to DOM */
```

BTW, this data structure:

```
const data = [{...}, {...},...]
```

is an array `[...]` of objects `{...}`. A multidimensional array looks like this:

```
[[...], [...], [...], ...]
```

```js
const countries = [{
    name: 'Belgium',
    population: 11.46,
    km: 30689
  },
  {
    name: 'France',
    population: 67.06,
    km: 643801
  },
  {
    name: 'USA',
    population: 238.2,
    km: 9834000
  },
  {
    name: 'Russia',
    population: 144.4,
    km: 17130000
  },
  {
    name: 'China',
    population: 1398,
    km: 9597000
  },
];

const list = document.getElementById('countries');

countries.forEach(country => {
  let opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = JSON.stringify(country);
  opt.textContent = country.name;
  list.append(opt);
});

list.onchange = countryStats;

function countryStats(e) {
  const data = JSON.parse(this.value);
  const htmlString = `
    <dl>
      <dt>Country</dt>
      <dd>${data.name}</dd>
      <dt>Population</dt>
      <dd>${data.population} million</dd>
      <dt>Area</dt>
      <dd>${data.km} km</dd>
    </dl>`;
  const display = document.querySelector('output');
  display.replaceChildren();
  display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
}
```

```css
select {
  font: inherit
}

dt {
  font-weight: 700
}

dd {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select id='countries'>
  <option selected>----</option>
</select>
<output></output>
```

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks for helping me out! <3